# For Each over a getList()?

Tags: java, foreach

```
myClass a = new myClass();
for (Object o : a.getList()) system.out.println("hi");
```

Should I first make a variable to hold a.getList(), or is the above code okay?

Comment: As you can see in the duplicate, the `List`'s `Iterator` is already stored in a hidden variable. There's no need for you to store the `List` value explicitly.

Comment: @RedRoboHood This is example code, which does not belong at Code Review.